# How to check values in column in Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check whether the column middle name contain any value or not.
If it is empty, then it should not be concatenated with the name.

```
    Select
     ..
     Agent,
     FirstName + ' ' MiddleName + ' ' + LastName as Name,
     ...
     from tbSystemUser
```

In above query it adds space two times in Name if MiddleName is empty.

Comment: Will the `Middlename` be `NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CASE expression` with `COALESCE` in following:

```
 select
 ..
 Agent,
 case when coalesce(MiddleName, '') = '' then FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
      else FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName 
 end as Name,
 ...
 from tbSystemUser
```

Comment: Adding +1 for handling null and empty by coalesce.

Comment: I'd rather have a constraint that disallowed empty names. (To force NULL's.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement

```
Select
     ..
     Agent,
     Case MiddleName
     when ' ' then
     FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
     else
     FirstName + ' ' MiddleName + ' ' + LastName
     end
     as Name,
     ...
     from tbSystemUser
```

OR

```
Select
         ..
         Agent,
         Case 
         when MiddleName = ' ' then
         FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
         else
         FirstName + ' ' MiddleName + ' ' + LastName
         end
         as Name,
         ...
         from tbSystemUser
```

Comment: Syntax error. BTW, you want a case expression, not a case statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
 ..
 Agent,
 FirstName + CASE WHEN MiddleName is not null THEN  ' ' + MiddleName else '' END  + ' ' + LastName as Name,
 ...
 from tbSystemUser
```

Comment: Same problem as before. Move `+ '  '` into the case expression. (And adjust the syntax error.)

Comment: Better, but still syntax error. (Hint: just before case.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a case expression to only add the `MiddleName + ' '` part if MiddleName is not null:

```
Select
     ...
     Agent,
     FirstName +
     case when MiddleName is not null then MiddleName + ' ' end +
     LastName as Name,
     ...
     from tbSystemUser
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use subqueries as such:

```
 Select Agent, Name from
 (
     Select t1.Agent as Agent, t1.FirstName + ' ' t1.MiddleName + ' ' + t1.LastName as Name,
     from tbSystemUser as t1 WHERE t1.MiddleName IS NOT NULL
 )
 NATURAL JOIN 
 (
      Select t2.Agent as Agent, t2.FirstName + ' ' + t2.LastName as Name,
      from tbSystemUser as t2 WHERE t2.MiddleName IS NULL
 )
```

This will construct your answer based on the Name created by the two selects.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName 
   +IIF(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(MiddleName)),'')<>'',' '+MiddleName,'')
   +' '+LastName as Name
```

Or in case your SQL Server version is older than 2012:

```
SELECT FirstName 
   +CASE WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(MiddleName))) <> '' 
      THEN ' '+MiddleName
      ELSE '' END
   +' '+LastName as Name
```

You didn't specify what empty meant. Unlike most of the other solutions here, this will deal with any length of empty strings including nulls, but not special characters. I'm going to assume nobody went and added line breaks as middle names? :)